# WAMP server Icon is red but it shows that it is online, could not open the localhost

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, wampserver

I use wampserver 2.4 with php 5.4 , for 64bits in windows platform.

I have a problem with wampserver. It shows a red icon but it tell me that it online, 
when I tried to open the localhost it doesn't show the localhost for the wampserver , "Unable to connect" that what shows in Firefox.

I tested the port 80 and the result was **" your port 80 is not actually used "**
Then,I uninstall the Skype to make sure there is no conflicting between them. 
I reinstall the Apache but nothings changed.

I opened **start>control panel>administration tool> services**, and check the proprieties for the server and it was stop, and the icon 'start' was gray so i couldn't change it.

**So I  reinstall the wampserve and the localhost worked but the icon still read.**

I want to connect the MSsql data , so i install the drive files '**.dll**' then added the needed ones in **wamp\php\ext**. then added the extension in the **php.ini**, then restart the wampserver. when i restarted it, the problem came back again and the localhost doesn't work. i tried to remove the extensions that i added in **php.ini** and restart the wampserver again, but nothing solved.

i've been looking for a solution for three days and tried almost every thing i found in the internet. but it still not working. so i register to stack over flow to present my problem to you.

***pleas help me.***

Leanah

Comment: In new versions of WAMPServer, you have to use http://127.0.0.1 - Does this work for you? If not we can look at other things.

Comment: present which port you are using ?

Comment: Use net stop HTTP Command for stoping all 80 port processes and then start wamp

Comment: thank you for the fast response, but no the 127.0.0.1 is not working with me.

Comment: @LokiSinclair its more when u are on windows8 u need to 127.0.0.1 otherwise mysql will be slow as hell

Comment: I had a similar issue with an installation of WAMP I had copied from another machine - localhost was not accessible and nothing in the error logs. Installing over the copied files didn't help but then uninstalling and reinstalling did.

Answer (score 2):

The online/offline does not mean that Apache has started. It means you have set it online which changes the `Allow from localhost` to `Allow from all` in the httpd.conf. And that is all it means.

If the wampmanager icon is RED then neither the Apache(wampapahe) or MysQL(wampmysql) services have started. Therefore Apache and MySQL are not running and nothing will work.

You need to find out what is causing this problem.

If the Apache error log and mysql error logs are empty then look at the `Windows event viewer` for error messages from both Apache and MySQL.

**I see you want to connect to MSSQL.** In that case you have to use the **32bit WAMPServer, as microsoft only produce a 32 bit version of php_mssql**. So you will have to uninstall the 64bit WAMPServer, then go and maually delete the `\wamp\...` folder structure.

Then install WAMPServer 32bit.

Before you install the 32 bit make sure that you have the following 32bit MS C++ runtime libraries installed on your system.

Please make sure you have the latest version of all of these Microsoft C/C++ Redistributable runtime libraries. You dont need the whole compiler, just these C/C++ runtime libraries.

*PS. These are just libraries and NOT the whole compiler.*

```
The 2008 Redist (32bit) is used by wampmanager even if you installed the 64bit WAMPServer.
The 2010 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used ).
The 2012 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used ).
```

**FOR WAMP 32bit**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) [Link1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) [Link2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 32bit and therefore Apache 2.4.x**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 is required [LInk3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679) And select vcredist_x86.exe

**FOR WAMP 64bit**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  [Link4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

> > Yes you need the x86 Package regardless as wampmanager uses this <<

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64) [Link5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) [Link6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 64bit**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 [Link7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679) And select vcredist_x64.exe

Comment: thank you so much, i will do what u did u mention above and tell you the results, thanx again

Comment: i uninstall the 64bit and install the 32bit WAMPServer , even installing the MS C++ runtime libraries. the localhost and the 127.0.0.1 worked but the icon still read, and when i added the .dll for the mssql and restarted the wampserver. the problem came back again and nither the localhost or the 127.0.0.1 worked. :(

Comment: If icon is red and localhost worked, then you have another Apache and maybe another MySQL installed and running.

Comment: at the beginning yes, but when i restarted it the local host stopped. but how can i check if there is another Apache or MySQL running,nothing there in the control panel

Comment: Look in the services panel. Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services. WAMP's services are called `wampapache` and `wampmysql` If you have another set the will be called `Apache` and `MySQL`

Answer (score 0):

i tried to reinstall every thing trying to figure out what causing this problem. wampserver still **read** and when i run the Redistributable Package it said " **setup failed. one or more issues caused the setup to fail, please fix the issues and then retry setup**",, again i checked the port 80 and nothing is used by it, i do all the previous steps but still nothing. i opened the Apache log error and it shows this:

[Thu Feb 20 09:54:42.305846 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3532:tid 440] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Feb 20 09:54:42.305846 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3532:tid 440] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34

[Thu Feb 20 09:54:42.305846 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3532:tid 440] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'

[Thu Feb 20 09:54:42.305846 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3532:tid 440] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2900

[Thu Feb 20 09:54:43.023464 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2900:tid 324] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

[Thu Feb 20 10:14:27.138239 2014] [:error] [pid 2900:tid 1508] [client ::1:50145] script 'C:/wamp/www/info.php' not found or unable to stat

[Thu Feb 20 10:47:11.156800 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3532:tid 440] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.

[Thu Feb 20 10:47:13.184804 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2900:tid 324] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.

[Thu Feb 20 10:47:16.897611 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3532:tid 440] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2900 exited successfully.

**i hope it will tell you something that i didn't get.**

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a solution, the wampserver is still read, but at least its working and the connection of the firebird data base worked.

when i test port 80 from the wamp it shows nothing there, but when i opened the CMD and write " netstat -aon | findstr :80" this command will present any thig using the port 80 with their PID, so i toke the PID's and checked them in "start task manager" and found there was another apache running :O , so i uninstall it from the CMD, and start running the both WampApache and WampMySql, and yeeeh, the local host worked and the data base connection worked to. but the wampserver stil read lol. at least i get what i want. thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that worked for me:**

1. Access services.msc (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services);
2. Find all the services that start with `"wamp"`. In my case: `wampapache64` and `wampmysqld64`;
3. Double click on each of them and set the start-up type as: `"automatic"`;
4. Restart all services of wamp, by clicking once on its tray icon and selecting the option `"Restart All Services"`.

I don't know why, but, somehow, the services start-up types where marked as `"Disabled"`. Maybe some other software made it without my consent. Because of that, the **Wamp** was with a **red icon**, but showing **online** when hoovering the mouse over it.

[image: wamp red icon but online cause]